# Docker image for windows components

Tags: linux, windows, docker

I have a python script which is used for testing. This script also uses 'scommand' tool. Its a windows command line tool(basically a .bat file) to execute SOATEST related things (https://cloudlink.soasta.com/t5/CloudTest-Knowledge-Base/Using-SCommand-to-Deploy-and-Manage-Grids/ta-p/44613).

I downloaded Python image and was able to execute few sample python scripts. But to run this code, I need 'scommand'.  I searched online and did not find any image for 'scommand'. I am using docker in a Ubuntu machine and 'scommand' is a windows tool. Is there any way, I can get an image of this tool which can work on linux/unix machine? I cannot use a windows machine.

Is there any way that I can only make an image of this tool so that unix/linux docker engine can use it? Or is there any version of docker which can run in Ubuntu and can also take Windows apps also? I am using following version of docker.

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Docker cannot help you with running Windows code on a Linux machine, as containers share the operating system with the host machine.

However, according to the [scommand reference](https://cloudlink.soasta.com/t5/CloudTest-Knowledge-Base/SCommand-Reference/ta-p/43103), there is a Unix version of the software available. In order to get a working image, you can write a Dockerfile based on the Python image in which you download and install the Unix version of `scommand` (using `wget` etc.).

Comment: Thanks a lot Karl.